# expect_any_instance_of with an object argument

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am testing a class's initialization block as below

```
class A
  attr_accessor :client

  def initialize(options, configuration)
    self.client = B.new(options)
    config = C.new(
      url: configuration[:url],
      headers: configuration[:headers],
      username: configuration[:username],
      password: configuration[:password]
    )
    client.configure(config)
  end
end

class C
  def initialize(options)
    # does something with options hash
  end
end

class B
  def initialize(options)
    # does something with options hash
  end

  def configure(config)
    # some configuration with config object
  end
end
```

My test case is as follows:

```
let(:options) {
  {
    force_basic_auth: true
  }
}

let(:configuration) {
  {
    url: 'https://localhost:3000',
    headers: { awesome: true },
    username: 'test',
    password: 'pass'
  }
}

let(:api_config) {
  C.new(configuration)
}

it 'configures object with passed params' do
  expect_any_instance_of(B).to receive(:configure)
    .with(api_config)

  A.new(
    options,
    configuration
  )
end
```

This fails my test case because the object that is created in the initialization block has a different `object_id` than the `object_id` of api_config which I am using in the expectations.

```
   -[#<C:0x00000002b51128 @url="https://localhost:3000", @headers={:awesome=>true}, @username="test", @password="pass">]
   +[#<C:0x00000002a1b628 @url="https://localhost:3000", @headers={:awesome=>true}, @username="test", @password="pass">]
```

Seeing that failure I was thinking whether it's a best practice to pass such objects directly in the initialization block. I mean I can fix it by directly passing the object in the initialization block. 
There are many functions which are initializing the `A` class with a hash option being passed because of which I am doing it in the current way.

Is there a way to expect the contents of the object passed in rspec instead of verifying the objects are same ? Is passing the object directly in the initialization a more better approach ?

Comment: What is `B`? What is `Config`? are they the same?

Comment: @UriAgassi Sorry about that, I can't paste the exact code so I changed the class names. I've added the minimum definition of `B` and `C` class required for the problem. Let me know if I've missed anything else. Thanks :)

Comment: shouldn't `api_config` be of type `C`?

Answer (score 1):

You can define arbitrary expectation handling to check the value of the parameter checked (see [here](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/configuring-responses/block-implementation)):

```
it 'configures object with passed params' do
  expect_any_instance_of(B).to receive(:configure) do |config|
     expect(config).to be_a(C)
     expect(config.url).to eq(configuration[:url])
     expect(config.headers).to eq(configuration[:headers])
     # ...
  end

  A.new(
    options,
    configuration
  )
end
```

Comment: I tried this locally, the `config` is `B`'s object not `C`'s object.

Comment: I need to compare the contents of the object that is passed to configure method and the hash configuration.

Comment: the `config` in my test above is the `C` instance passed to `B.configure`. You should add any needed expectation in the block to verify it is the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

You want the configuration hash (rather than the object) under `B.configure(config)`, so your class has to change slightly to accommodate.

Class file

```
class A
  attr_accessor :client

  def initialize(options, configuration)
    self.client = B.new(options)
    config = C.new(
      url: configuration[:url],
      headers: configuration[:headers],
      username: configuration[:username],
      password: configuration[:password]
    )
    client.configure(config.options)
  end
end

class C
  attr_reader :options

  def initialize(options)
    @options = options
  end
end

class B
  def initialize(options)
    # does something with options hash
  end

  def configure(config)
    # some configuration with config object
  end
end
```

Here's what your RSpec code would look like.

```
describe do
  let(:options) do
    {
      force_basic_auth: true
    }
  end

  let(:configuration) do
    {
      url: 'https://localhost:3000',
      headers: { awesome: true },
      username: 'test',
      password: 'pass'
    }
  end

  let(:my_a_object) { A.new(options, configuration) }
  let(:my_b_object) { B.new(options) }

  it 'configures object with passed params' do
    allow(B).to receive(:new).with(options).and_return(my_b_object)

    expect(my_b_object).to receive(:configure).with(configuration)
    my_a_object
  end
end
```